# Cyclic dependencies between main-test modules in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm trying to make what looks like a "circular dependency" in sbt (I know there has to be another way to structure the project but for the set of 
constraints I'm dealing with right now, it seems like a reasonable trade-off).

I'm not 100% these dependencies should be considered "circular" given we only need `core/test` to know about `impl`. Anyways, here is what my `sbt.build` looks like now:

```
lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
   .dependsOn(LocalProject("impl") % "test")

lazy val impl = (project in file("impl"))
  .dependsOn(core)
```

Obviously, sbt complains about that in terms of `Cyclic reference involving`.

FWIW, I quite seamlessly expressed this kind of build in Pants. Is there a way to do that in sbt as well?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to have cyclic depencies in sbt. I it is kind of strange that your core module depends on tests right, can you explain why that is?